# Vue-js call object with special id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a newbie in Vue-js and really need your help:

In my Django project I have 2 models: Patient and MedCard of this patient. They are connected with a Foreign Key. I want to implement such functionality: on page "Patients" I have list of patients, then when I push on someone's name I want to see his/her MedCard.

This is my code, but when I push on name I get all records for all patients from MedCard model:

Patients.vue:

```
<div v-for="patient in patients">
    <h3 @click="openMedCard(patient.id)">{{patient.surname}} {{patient.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{patient.birth_date}}</p>
</div>
<div
    <MedCard v-if="med_record.show" :id="med_record.id"></MedCard>
</div>

export default {
    name: 'Patient',
    components: {
        MedCard,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            patients: '',
            med_record: {
                  patient: '',
                  show: false,
                }
            }
        }
```

and methods from Patient.vue:

```
methods: {
openMedCard(id) {
    this.med_record.patient = id
    this.med_record.show = true
}
```

MedCard.vue:

```
<template>
<mu-row v-for="med_record in med_records">
    <h3>Doc – {{med_record.doc.surname}}{{med_record.doc.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{med_record.patient.surname}}</p>
    <p>{{med_record.record}}</p>
    <small>{{med_record.date}}</small>
</mu-row>
</template>

export default {
    name: 'MedCard',
    props: {
        id: '',
    },
    data() {
        return {
            med_records: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadMedCard() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/hospital/med_card/",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    id: this.id,
                    patient: this.patient
                },
                success: (response) => {
                    this.med_records = response.data.data
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

loadMedCard() gives me info from all MedCards in JSON like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "patient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "surname": "KKK",
                    "name": "KKK",
                    "patronymic": "LLL",
                    "birth_date": "1999-07-07",
                    "sex": "F",
                    "phone": "no_phone",
                    "email": "no_email"
                },
                "doc": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "surname": "DDD",
                    "name": "DDD",
                    "patronymic": "DDD",
                    "education": "d",
                    "category": "2",
                    "sex": "m",
                    "phone": "no_phone",
                    "email": "no_email"
                },
                "record": "test text",
                "date": "2020-06-09"
            }...]
```

I'll be grateful for any help!

Comment: I can help you, but I cannot understand what exactly the problem is? Can you explain in more details?

Best Regards,

Comment: Your `MedCard` component is missing the `patient` prop.

Comment: @NikolayYankov thanks for you answer! Some details: for example I have Patient1 and Patient2. When I push on Patient1 I want to get information only from his MedCard, but my code works not in this way, it gives me MedCards of Patient1 and Patient2 both. And I don't really know how to make it work in an appropriate way.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I've added it, but nothing changed(

Comment: Well, what kind of response do you get from your API call in loadMedCard(), is it data for one record only? How does the template for MedCard.vue look like?

Comment: @NikolayYankov I've updated the question, check please)

Comment: @DaryaShipitcyna where you have `..:id="med_record.id"></MedCard>` in Patients.vue should that not be  `..:id="med_record.patient"></MedCard>`?

Comment: @steve16351 I've also tried it, but it doesn't help:(

Answer (score 0):

So the API returns you multiple patients's data while you're asking it for just one exact patient. There must be something wrong with the API with the filtering in first place. So you can filter your data on the client side, in your `MedCard.vue` component. First this component have to show data for one patient only, so the `v-for="med_record in med_records"` is not needed. Your `med_records` property can become just an object not an array:

```
data() {
        return {
            med_record: {},
        }
}
```

And in the success resolve method of your API call you can filter only the data you need and store it in `med_record`

```
success: (response) => {
                    this.med_records = response.data.data.find((patient)=> { return patient.id === this.id})
                }
```

If you want to store all the data in the `med_records`, then you can create computed property and apply the same filtering there.

I hope this helps.